useRouter() is not redirecting to the landing page
"use client"
import { useState } from 'react';
import {auth} from '../../firebase-config'
import {createUserWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const SignUp = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
       const router = useRouter();
        
        e.preventDefault();
        // Handle form submission here (e.g., send data to server)
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth , email,password)
        .then(()=>{
            setEmail('');
            setPassword('');
            router.push('/')
        }).catch((err)=>{
            throw console.log(err);
        })
    }


I have used useEffect hook , windows.location.href , I have restarted my server but nothing works.
I want the user to redirect to landing page but it seems nothing is working.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In your current implementation, the useRouter() hook is being called inside the handleSubmit function, which is likely causing issues with the routing. In Next.js, hooks need to be called at the top level of your component, not within any callbacks or nested functions.
const SignUp = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
       ...
    }
...


Move this line const router = useRouter(); right after importing it, calling it inside the SignUp is restriciting its usage. router needs to be accessable at the top level.
"use client"
import { useState } from 'react';
import {auth} from '../../firebase-config'
import {createUserWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const router = useRouter();
const SignUp = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      ...
    }


